# winapi - Get and/or Change my hook's order and priority

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

my name is Dylan Michaels.

I've created a low-level mouse hook in my Win32 C++ program and I'm aware that many applications can have hooks and Microsoft Windows sends the messages to these hooks one at a time, like a chain. I want to know if I can get my hook's place in this chain and maybe even alter it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API does not expose any way to determine your hook's position within the chain, and no way to alter the ordering of the chain other than when calling `SetWindowsHookEx()`.

Comment: Exactly.  Dylan, think--what would happen if two programs tried to do this?

Comment: Alright, thanks Remy and jeffamaphone, that's the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @jeffamaphone I “think” a lot and I found several legitimate uses for this; for instance guarding against buggy, uncooperative software that forgets to call `CallNextHookEx()`.